# Silverlight chart colours change on every refresh

Tags: silverlight, charts

Hi I am adding series to silverlight column chart from code behind. On click button event i first clear the series and then dynamically add series. Now i find that every time colour changes randomly irrespective of whether no of series changes or not. 
Say on 1st time click event two series got added and chart has say color 1 and color2. Next time even if exactly two series are added(off course after clearing existing previous series) i may get color 3 and color 3. Same thing i observed in different chart types. How to get consistent colors without binding colors in template. I am using silverlight version 5.0
The only way i can obtain same colours is in the following case. Suppose i define n (say 5) colours in the template and every time add exactly n series. Now if i add 4 1st time it displays 1st 4 color. Now next time if i add 4 it will display from 2 to 5. It means it cyclically tries to display all the colours defined in it.

Comment: You can create several styles for `DataPoint` and set them explicitly to the `DataPointStyle` proeprty of series.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with recreating Chart in code behind, instead using binding in XAML.

```
Chart chartUsers = new Chart();
chartUsers.Palette = palette; 
chartUsers.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
chartUsers.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
chartUsers.Title = Resources["DashboardUsersTitle"].ToString();
chartUsers.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["ChartStyle1"]; //my style
chartUsers.Height = 250;
gridFirstRow.Children.Add(chartUsers);
```

Now you can create series,axis and bind stuff to them.

You can have your custom colors added to pallete, like this (example):

```
private void CreateChartPalette()
    {
        List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();
        colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 88, 113, 165));
        colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 78, 149, 51));//dark green
        colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 32, 153, 161));//green-blue
        colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 201, 152, 0));//orange
        colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 166, 22, 22));//ref
        colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 196, 192, 85));//yellow
        colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 86, 168, 117));//light green
        colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 117, 49, 49));//dark red
        colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 195, 146, 0));//orange 2
        colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 126, 86));//dark yellow
        colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 86, 121, 128));//dark blue
        colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 58, 115, 25));//dark green
        colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 126, 147, 152));//grey-blue
        colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 111, 169, 133));//light green 2
        colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 97, 55, 96));//purple
        colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 250, 229, 166));//yellow
        colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 72, 109, 117));//dark blue 2

        palette = new ResourceDictionaryCollection();

        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < colors.Count; i++)
        {
            LinearGradientBrush lgb = new LinearGradientBrush();
            lgb.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
            lgb.EndPoint = new Point(0.5, 1);

            GradientStop gsBegin = new GradientStop();
            gsBegin.Color = Color.FromArgb(128, colors[i].R, colors[i].G, colors[i].B);
            gsBegin.Offset = 0;

            GradientStop gsEnd = new GradientStop();
            gsEnd.Color = colors[i];
            gsEnd.Offset = 1;

            lgb.GradientStops.Add(gsBegin);
            lgb.GradientStops.Add(gsEnd);

            Style style = new Style(typeof(DataPoint));
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(BackgroundProperty, lgb));

            ResourceDictionary dictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
            dictionary.Add("DataPointStyle", style);

            palette.Add(dictionary);
        }
    }
```